# How to eject a DVD without logging in my Mac?

Tags: mac, optical-drive, dvd, eject

I can not log in my Mac and I want to eject CD/DVD.

[image]

Comment: So you want to abort the installation? Click "annuler"

Comment: Abort the installation go to the terminal and `drutil eject` (CD - DVD) or `unmount YOUR_DISK`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reboot your Mac and immediately hold the (left) mouse button or the trackpad until the CD/DVD is ejected.